# Converting an Ant fileset to multiple apply args

Tags: ant, arguments, fileset

I have some files:

```
dir/foo.txt
dir/bar.txt
dir/foobar.txt
```

In an Ant `apply` task, I want to pass the list of files as arguments:

```
<target name="atask">
    <apply executable="${cmd}" parallel="false" verbose="true">
        <arg value="-in"/>
        <srcfile/>
        <arg value="dir/foo.txt"/>
        <arg value="dir/bar.txt"/>
        <arg value="dir/foobar.txt"/>

        <fileset dir="${list.dir}" includes="*.list"/>
    </apply>
</target>
```

This works fine, but what if I want to pick the list of files dynamically, using a fileset:

```
<fileset dir="dir" includes="*.txt"/>
```

How can I convert this fileset to `arg` elements - one per file? Something like:

```
<arg>
    <fileset dir="dir" includes="*.txt"/>
</arg>
```

instead of

```
<arg value="dir/foo.txt"/>
<arg value="dir/bar.txt"/>
<arg value="dir/foobar.txt"/>
```

*(This example doesn't work because **arg** doesn't support **fileset**)*

Answer (score 28):

Here's an example illustrating the use of the [pathconvert](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html) task.

The converted path is passed to the executable using `<arg line />`.

This assumes no spaces in the paths of your `*.txt` files.

```
<target name="atask">
    <fileset dir="dir" id="myTxts">
        <include name="*.txt" />
    </fileset>
    <pathconvert property="cmdTxts" refid="myTxts" pathsep=" " />

    <apply executable="${cmd}" parallel="false" verbose="true">
        <arg value="-in" />
        <srcfile />
        <arg line="${cmdTxts}" />

        <fileset dir="${list.dir}" includes="*.list" />
    </apply>
</target>
```

If you might encounter spaces this should do: as above, but change (hopefully obvious which lines) to:

```
    <pathconvert property="cmdTxts" refid="myTxts" pathsep="' '" />
```

and

```
        <arg line="'${cmdTxts}'"/>
```

Comment: I thought It was not possible to mix <arg value= /> and <arg line= /> but it seems to be OK. This is a nice workaround and it works (I have not tested the case with spaces in the names).

Comment: [Quote:](https://ant.apache.org/manual/using.html#arg) *It is highly recommended to avoid the line version when possible. Ant will try to split the command line in a way similar to what a (Unix) shell would do, but may create something that is very different from what you expect under some circumstances.*