# Is there a common way to access the resulting fileset of an ANT task?

Tags: ant, fileset

I'm trying to write a replacement of the integrated `<zip>` task so that it supports passwords using `<exec>` and `7za.exe`. The idea is to have a drop-in replacement of the `<zip>` task.

The difficulty is, that `<zip>` support so many ways to declare which files to include/exclude such as:

- `includes`
- `includesfile`
- `excludes`
- `excludesfile`
- `defaultexcludes`
- and nested `<fileset>` declarations

Is there a way to use the result of these `fileset` instructions inside the exec task?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2151078/1268685) I was able to come up with a solution which works similar to the integrated `<zip>` task. Using `<pathconvert>` and single quotes does the trick:

```
<macrodef name="sevenzip" description="Command line interface for 7zip">
    <attribute name="level"  default="5"/> <!-- will be ignored for now, just to make it compatible with normal ZIP task -->
    <attribute name="basedir"/>
    <attribute name="excludes" default=""/>
    <attribute name="includes" default="**/**"/>
    <attribute name="destfile"/>
    <attribute name="password" default=""/>

    <sequential>
        <description>7-Zip integration</description>
        <local name="passArg" />
        <if>
            <equals arg1="@{password}" arg2=""/>
            <then>
                <property name="passArg" value="" />
            </then>
            <else>
                <!-- p<SECRET> = set password of archive -->
                <property name="passArg" value='"-p@{password}"' />
            </else>
        </if>

        <fileset id="mask" dir="@{basedir}">
            <include name="@{includes}" />
            <exclude name="@{excludes}" />
        </fileset>

        <local name="mask" />
        <pathconvert property="mask" refid="mask" pathsep="' '" />
        <!-- the single quotes help to wrap file names containing spaces -->

        <exec executable="${7zip.cmd}" failonerror="true">
            <!-- command -->
            <arg value="a"/>                <!-- a : add files to archive -->
            <!-- arg value="u"/ -->             <!-- u : update files to archive -->

            <!-- switches -->
            <arg value="-bd"/>              <!-- -bd : disable percentage indicator -->
            <arg value="-tzip"/>            <!-- -t<type> : set type of archive -->             

            <arg value="${passArg}"/>       

            <arg value="--"/>               <!-- : Stop switches parsing -->

            <!-- archive file -->
            <arg value="@{destfile}"/>

            <!-- file names / wildcards -->
            <arg line="'${mask}'"/>
            <!-- 
                the single quotes are the outter wrapper for the single quotes
                from pathconvert, the line attribute add the result to the arguments
                but NOT as a single escaped string
            -->

        </exec>
    </sequential>
</macrodef>
```

Answer (score 0):

The undocumented property `${toString:filesetid}` has all files, default separator is ';'.
To convert the separator use [pathconvert task](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/pathconvert.html),  the resulting property will contain the files with choosen separator, f.e. :

```
<fileset dir="C:/diff1" includes="**/*.html" id="diff">
 <different targetdir="C:/diff2"
   ignoreFileTimes="true"/>
</fileset>

<!-- one file one line -->
<pathconvert refid="diff" pathsep="${line.separator}" property="htmldiff"/>

<!-- blank as separator -->
<pathconvert refid="diff" pathsep=" " property="htmldiff"/>  

<echo file="C:/diff1/htmldiff.txt">${htmldiff}</echo>
```

for use in exec with arg line, blank as separator seems appropiate.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. My solution is something along these lines.